# how to access forms field in django?

Tags: python, django, forms, web, web-frameworks

This is my forms:

```
class signup_form(forms.ModelForm):
    bio = forms.TextInput()
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username',
                  'password',
                  'first_name',
                  'last_name', 
                  'email',
                  'date_joined']
```

And This one is my template page:

```
urlpatterns = [
    ......
    url(r'^profile/(?P<username>[\w\-]+)/$', user_profile, name='user_profile'),
]
```

And this is signup template page:

```
{% extends parent_template|default:"tick/base_tick.html" %}

{% block title %}
{{ block.super }} ---> Sign Up HERE!!
{% endblock %}


{% block content %}
    <div>
        <div>
            <form action="{% url 'user_profile' username={{ form.username }} %}" method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{form.as_p}}
                <button type="submit">Create User</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

As you can see in the 'action' part of the  form i want to access to the 'username' field of 'form' but i can't and the Django get me some error.

What Should I do?

Edit: This is the Error
[image]

Comment: Please post the Django error here.

Comment: @SHIVAMJINDAL I put the error in the Question post. one thing that i should mention is that after adding  '' .value'' nothing changed.!!

Comment: @SHIVAMJINDAL unfortunately it didn't work again...!!

Comment: I will update my answer tomorrow

Answer (score 1):

Value of a field is accessed by form.field_name.value. Use can update your code by below code

```
<form action="{% url 'user_profile' username=from.username.value %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p}}
    <button type="submit">Create User</button>
</form>
```

Comment: The issue is that `form.username.vale`  initially have '' blank and after updating in form it does reflect in `form.username.value` directly. You should call a function on `onchange` event of input field and update `action` attribute via JS.